# How to create multipart rar file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, rar

How can I create multipart rar file in Linux using the official console rar client?

```
RAR 3.90   Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Alexander Roshal   16 Aug 2009
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help
```

I want a multipart rar with each part size being 150 MB.

Comment: Why use RAR? There are a lot of other file formats out there, ones that people don't file lawsuits over and are still widely used in 2010, like 7z, tgz, zip.

Comment: I too recommend 7z (p7zip) implementation. Not only it's a program free to use on Linux, but you also have a better compression rate.

Comment: OK, I have asked this question for 7zip, too.  Please help!  http://superuser.com/questions/184557/how-to-create-multipart-7zip-file-in-linux

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
rar a -v153600k <name-of-archive-file> <files-to-compressed>
```

will create 150Mb multipart rar archives

Personally, I'd use 7zip or bzip2 than rar, but that's my opinion