# How to create multipart 7zip file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, 7-zip

How can I create a multipart 7zip  file in Linux using the p7zip console client?

Many people referred me to it.  My console app is

```
7-Zip [64] 9.13 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-04-15
p7zip Version 9.13 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)
```

Comment: IMO the best solution is to avoid 7-zip and use xz. To split archives, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120095/split-files-using-tar-gz-zip-or-bzip2

Comment: Thank you. I'm not even for sure the xz option was even standard on most distros when I originally asked this question.

Comment: I came back to my question after 13 years ;-) 7z v17.05

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use the `-v` option (v is for volume) `-v100m` will split the archive into chunks of 100MB.

7z `-v` option supports `b k m g` (bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes)

Example:
`7z -v100m a my_zip.7z my_folder/`

Comment: Be aware that 7zip doesn't preserve file ownership information on Linux.

Comment: 7z seem not to append files if file are already in the archive or if archive already exists.

Comment: Also works on OSX using `brew install p7zip`.

Comment: Full command example: `7z -v100m a my_zip.7z my_folder/`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, thx, we can tar b4 7z then naming archive.tar.7z ! file-roller accepted opening archive.tar.7z.001 file properly and I confirmed the permissions and ownership with `tar -tvf` on the extracted tar file :)

Comment: The example command creates 100m volumes named `my_zip.7z.001`, `my_zip.7z.002`, etc.  
To extract from these volumes, use this command: `7z e my_zip.7z.001`.
Even though you are specifying only the the first part in the command, the command will look for all the parts in the same folder and extract it.